# How to determine the virtual directory for apex after installation

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I've installed apex in my database. 
@apexins.sql sysaux sysaux temp /i/

is there a way to determine what was the virtual directory ( /i/ ) value given during installation?
any tables to query & check which has the reference of this value?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Image Prefix changes in Oracle Application Express 4.2.2](http://joelkallman.blogspot.hr/2013/05/image-prefix-changes-in-oracle.html) (disregard the Apex version), written by Joel Kallman, *the Director of Software Development at Oracle who manages the development and product management of Application Express*. Hopefully, you'll find it interesting.

Comment: The doc link in that article is broken, so just search for *APEX_APPLICATION.G_IMAGE_PREFIX*

Comment: Hi @kfinity can you be a little more elaborate ? 
Can you provide me how to query with G_IMAGE_PREFIX in apex_application table ?

Comment: It's not a table, it's a PL/SQL package. Seriously, do a google search. `select APEX_APPLICATION.G_IMAGE_PREFIX from dual`

Comment: The query "select apex_application.g_image_prefix from dual" is appropriate.  You could also simply call the v() function when running in an APEX context, for example: select v('IMAGE_PREFIX') from dual